# Android's splitActionBarWhenNarrow doesn't work in Gingerbread when using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file has an Activity that looks like this:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/log_in"
    android:name=".activities.LogInActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

But unfortunately however, the split action bar doesn't seem to work on any device running a version of Android below Honeycomb (API 11). Instead, the menu items all appear on the top action bar and then overflow into the menu instead of splitting to the action bar below.

What gives?

Answer (score 4):

I was very close and just needed a tiny bit more XML to fix the issue:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
    android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

So now the XML would become this:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/log_in"
    android:name=".activities.LogInActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
        android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
```